# Laravel - getting relation in loop - best practices

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Just an example:
let's say I have Post model, and the Comment model.  Post, of course, have Comments, one-to-many relation.

I have to display list of posts with comments below it.

I'll get my posts in the controller:
`$posts = Post::get()`, I'll  pass it to the blade view and then I'll loop through it

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    {{ $post->comments }}
@endforeach
```

where `$post->comments` is some relation

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

As we know, that query will be executed many times.

Now my question: how we should optimize it?

1. Return `Cache::remember` in the getter?
2. Get (somehow?) those comments, when getting the posts in one query? Something like join query? I know that I can write that kind of query, but I'm talking about Eloquent's query builder. And then how get the comments within the loop? Wouldn't `{{ $post->comments }}` call  the relation again instead of getting stored data?
3. Different solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can do `$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()` to eager load the comments with the post. Read more about it in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Also, to display the comments you would want to add another foreach loop. It would look something like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
       {{ $comment->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: That looks fine, but what if I need some specific data with `with`? For example, I don't need all the comments, but just comment count?

Comment: Then you can use `withCount()`. Here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Answer (score 1):

You’ve probably cached some model data in the controller before, but I am going to show you a Laravel model caching technique that’s a little more granular using Active Record models

Note that we could also use the Cache::rememberForever() method and rely on our caching mechanism’s garbage collection to remove stale keys. I’ve set a timer so that the cache will be hit most of the time, with a fresh cache every fifteen minutes.

The cacheKey() method needs to make the model unique, and invalidate the cache when the model is updated. Here’s my cacheKey implementation:

```
public function cacheKey()
    {
        return sprintf(
            "%s/%s-%s",
            $this->getTable(),
            $this->getKey(),
            $this->updated_at->timestamp
        );
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function getCachedCommentsCountAttribute()
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->cacheKey() . ':comments_count', 15, function () {
            return $this->comments->count();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Will updating comments (adding/removing one) update the "updated_at" column in the Posts?

Comment: it will be when you  protected $touches = ['post']; put on Comment model

Comment: The $touches property is an array containing the association that will get “touched” when a comment is created, saved, or removed.

Comment: One more question - what If I use `with` with pagination? Then `with` should be just applied to the visible page.

I've just tested it and it applies to all records.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can do like that in controller

```
$minutes = 60;
$posts = Cache::remember('posts', $minutes, function () {
    return  Post::with('comments')->get()
});
```

in blade u can get like that

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
       {{ $comment->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

for more information read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache#obtaining-a-cache-instance)